# OCaml GADTs - pattern matching matches wrong type of argument

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, gadt

I have to implement **a perfectly balanced binary tree** (or PBT for short) using **generalized algebraic data types**. I have understood how GADTs work in general and the (somewhat ugly) syntax that I have to use in order for it to work in OCaml.
Then I have to implement some functions that work with it. Right now, I am having a problem with a function that takes two PBTs that have integers stored in their nodes and returns a PBT which stores in its nodes the sum of each of its corresponding nodes. Ok. Sounds easy enough.
This is the code that I have written for the PBT data type:

```
(*Important in order to define the index of the level of our perfectly 
balanced tree*)
(*Natural numbers, Peano style (now with GADTs)*)
type zero = Zero
type _ succ = Succ : 'natural -> 'natural succ

(*Implementing the perfectly balanced binary tree - or PBTree - with GADTs*)
(*'a -> type of tree | _ -> index of level*)

type ('a, _) pbtree =
(*Base case: empty tree - level 0, rock-bottom*)
EmptyTree : ('a, zero) pbtree
(*Inductive case: regular PBTree - tree on the left, value, tree on the 
right*)          
| PBTree : ('a, 'natural) pbtree * 'a * ('a, 'natural) pbtree -> ('a, 
'natural succ) pbtree
```

It worked so far. The type compiles and I even managed to do a flip function (return the mirror image of a PBT).
Now the real issue comes from this little brat:

```
let rec add : type int natural. 
(int, natural) pbtree -> (int, natural) pbtree -> (int, natural) pbtree =
function
| EmptyTree, EmptyTree -> EmptyTree
| PBTree(left1, value1, right1), PBTree(left2, value2, right2) -> 
PBTree((add left1 left2), value1 + value2, (add right1, right2))
```

Right where I do the pattern matching for the empty tree, it gives me the following error:

```
| EmptyTree, EmptyTree -> EmptyTree

Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a*'b
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
         (int, natural) pbtree
```

I can solve this if I make the function take a pair of trees. It would end up with the inductive case slightly changed and the function would look like this:

```
let rec add : type int natural. (int, natural) pbtree * (int, natural)         
pbtree -> (int, natural) pbtree =
function
| EmptyTree, EmptyTree -> EmptyTree
| PBTree(left1, value1, right1), PBTree(left2, value2, right2) -> 
PBTree((add (left1, left2)), value1 + value2, (add (right1, right2)))
```

However, this is not what I am supposed to do. My function needs to take two arguments. Even with this modification that solves the pair type conundrum, it will give the following error:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type int/1805
        but an expression was expected of type int/1
```

So the first approach I took is the best I can do.
My question is: why the pattern matching detects a pair when it is clearly not there? Why can it not detect two arguments like it normally should? Is it the way I wrote the function to detect that pattern?

If I, hypothetically, used the second approach in creating the function (the one where it took a pair of PBTs as an argument instead of two arguments - two PBTs), then why does it not recognise the integer value I am trying to give it to calculate? Is it maybe because it is too instrumented to work with?

I cannot understand what went wrong here and if I tried to modify the type to ease up on this syntactic restriction, then I risk creating a PBT that violates its own definition simply because of the type allowing branches which are unequal in size.

So again, I ask: why does pattern-matching fail to recognise the proper value types that I am giving it in the cases I presented?

Comment: I'm far from an expert on GADTs, but `type int natural.` defines two new locally abstract types called `int` and `natural` which will shadow any other types with that name in the scope of the function. It is not a type constraint. The error tells you that you that these type, which have the same name but different internal ids, are not compatible.

Comment: Just removing `int` from `type int natural.` seems to do the trick. Or at least it compiles.

Comment: Can confirm: `let rec add : type natural. (int, natural) pbtree -> (int, natural) pbtree -> (int, natural) pbtree =
fun tree1 tree2 -> match tree1, tree2 with` compiles.

Comment: And the first problem is just a misunderstanding I think. `EmptyTree, EmptyTree` is a pattern that matches a pair. In OCaml you don't need parenthesis if a tuple is delimited in other ways (yes, it's weird ;) ). And `function` takes only one argument, so you'll have to use `fun a b -> match a, b with ...`

Comment: And you shouldn't use a comma with `add right1, right2`. THEN the first one compiles too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last error you're getting:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type int/1805
       but an expression was expected of type int/1
```

is saying that there are two different `int` types that are not compatible, and gives you their internal ids so you can differentiate them. This error occurs because `type int natural.` creates two new locally abstract types scoped to the function, which will shadow any other types with those names within that scope. Resolving this error is simply done by not creating a locally abstract type named `int`. It will then constrain the type variable to the actual `int` type, as intended.

The other error:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a*'b
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
         (int, natural) pbtree
```

occurs because `EmptyTree, EmptyTree` actually *is* a pattern that matches a pair. In OCaml, tuples don't require parenthesis if they are delimited in other ways. So this, for example, is a valid (and extremely confusing) literal of type `(int * int) list`: `[1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6]`.

`function` is also restricted to only one argument, so in order to match on multiple arguments you need to use `fun a b -> match a, b with...`. Or you could just have `add` take a tuple directly.

Then finally you'll get an error because you use a comma to delimit function arguments in `add right1, right2` which, again, will be interpreted as a tuple instead. It should be `add right1 right2`.

The final working (or at least compiling) `add` function is then:

```
let rec add : type natural. 
(int, natural) pbtree -> (int, natural) pbtree -> (int, natural) pbtree =
fun a b -> match a, b with
| EmptyTree, EmptyTree -> EmptyTree
| PBTree(left1, value1, right1), PBTree(left2, value2, right2) -> 
PBTree((add left1 left2), value1 + value2, (add right1 right2))
```